# how to make volume bold and et. al italic when using the apalike bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I need to edit apalike file so that volume number apears in bold e.g. **1** and *et al.* in italic. Anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make a copy of apalike.bst, rename it e.g. myapalike.bst
2. To make volume bold find `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}`. 
   In this function replace line `{ volume field.or.null` with `{ "{\bfseries " volume "}" * * field.or.null`
3. To make et al italic find `FUNCTION {format.lab.names}`. 
   In this function make 2 replacements: 
   `% { pop$ "et~al." * }` should become `{ pop$ "\textit{ et~al.}" * }` 
   `{ " et~al." * }` should become `{ " \textit{et~al.}" * }`

Comment: `\bf` is an outdated command, use `\bfseries` Italic is `\textit{}` rather than `emph`

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit `et~al.` in `\textit{et~al.}` three times. The third one you will find in `FUNCTION {format.names}`.

Cheers