# Italic 'et al' using natbib and agsm...HOW?

Tags: citing

I am using **natbib** and **agsm** for harvard style referencing. My related code is

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

Then I am using `\citep{}` for citations. My problem is that in text I am getting (Author et al., 2012) and I want (Author *et al*., 2012). Does anyone know how to change this and get 'et al' in italics in the text?

Comment: Well, yes, it could be but why do you want to put it in italics? Ask yourself, what typographical meaning would it have with italics? [Should "et al." be written in italics, or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180515/should-et-al-be-in-italics)

Comment: @RunarTrollet Well I, for one, prefer my Latin (or any *auslaendische* [*i.e.*, foreign] phrase) in italics.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is will help you change to italics. For apa-good which also uses natbib, I only had one replacement to make. Don't forget to re-Typeset the bibliography (i.e. Latex -> Bibtex -> Latex -> Latex) after your changes. [how to make volume bold and et. al italic when using the apalike bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257976/how-to-make-volume-bold-and-et-al-italic-when-using-the-apalike-bibliography-st)